# Charset is not working correctly with French language

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

I have a problem with the french language on a website I`m developing ... I have menu bar, tabs and text within each tab ...

When I set the `charset=ISO-8859-1`, the text in the body works fine, but the menu bar and the tabs goes wrong!

This is a sample of the text I have ...

```
Menu Bar:  CONTRÃ”LE DE LA QUALITÃ‰    <<<<<<<<<<<<  Wrong
Tabs Text: CARRI&Atilde;&#136;RES      <<<<<<<<<<<<  Wrong
Body Text: égyptien                    <<<<<<<<<<<<  Correct
```

But when I set the `charset=utf-8`

```
Menu Bar:  CONTRÔLE DE LA QUALITÉ      <<<<<<<<<<<<  Correct
Tabs Text: CARRI&Atilde;&#136;RES      <<<<<<<<<<<<  Wrong
Body Text: �gyptien                   <<<<<<<<<<<<  Wrong
```

I have tried `mb_cenvert_encoding` to set the encoding, but it didn't also work ... Anyone have any idea how to let this work?

***UPDATE:***

[image: Website problem]

Comment: It’s most probable that the page contains characters in different encodings. That cannot possibly work. To fix this, you need to give access to the code that needs fixing. Also note that the HTTP headers may specify the encoding and then they override whatever you might set inside the document.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: how can I achieve this?

Comment: you could post the URL, or copy the content or sufficient part thereof (sufficient to demonstrate the problem) into jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hWjeg/ as you can see through the link, the french is good ... does the font affect the output on the HTML?

Comment: so what is the problem? You need to post some demo that illustrates the presence of a problem, not its absence. It might be best to post the actual page URL.

Comment: website is currently on localhost ... I'll add screenshots.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Screenshot added.

Comment: screenshots are of limited usefulness in debugging, but it looks sufficiently apparent that the page contains letters with diacritic marks both in ISO-8859-1 and in UTF-8 encoding. The only fix is to select one of them (or some other encoding) and use it consistently throughout the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've finally reached a solution ... You can call it a work around.

I've used [`iconv() PHP function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the encoding meta tag to your head?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

From [Declare the Encoding](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html).

Note that if you don't add this tag as the first tag of the `head`, some versions of FireFox will reload your pages after encountering this tag; this causes annoying 'double load' behaviour.

Comment: I have the meta tag exists in my code ... Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: but I use different charset as advised in the question above.